# How to send two parameters using one checkbox on its click event?

Tags: reactjs, this, setstate

What I want to do is that when the user clicks on the checkbox, the corresponding `companyid` should be passed to the function where I can update its activation status. But I am not able to send 2 values in one method.

I have searched on various websites and still not able to get any results.

This is How I am printing companies:

```
{this.state.allCompanies.map(com => (
                <tr>
                 <td>{com.cname} </td>
                  <td>
                    <a>
                        <input
                          type="checkbox"
                          name="active"
                          checked={com.is_active == 1 ? "true" : ""}
                          onClick={this.handleActivated(this, com.cid)}
                        />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

This is my `handleActivated` function:

```
handleActivated(e, id) {
    const active = e.target.name;
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.checked);

    this.setState({
      active: e.target.checked
    });

    // this.setState({  });
  }
```

This is my state.

```
this.state = {
      allCompanies: [],
      data: false,
      company: "",
      active: ""
    };
    this.handleActivated = this.handleActivated.bind(this);
```

What I want is `companyid` in the `handleActivated` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change onclick to this

```
onClick={event=>this.handleActivated(event,com.cid)}
```

Change your function to an arrow function

```
handleActivated =(e, id)=> {
    const active = e.target.name;
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.checked);

    this.setState({
      active: e.target.checked
    });

    // this.setState({  });
  }
```

Once you do that , then you can remove this from constructor , because it is no longer needed.

```
this.handleActivated = this.handleActivated.bind(this);
```

**This will give you more cleaner code**

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will help you.

```
onClick={(e) => this.handleActivated(e, com.cid)}
```